# Using Iesi ISet with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, iesi-collections

I'm missing something here!

I'm using ISet to map collection in my NHibernate winform c# project.

Now I want to do something like this:

```
Person _person=new Person();

Address _address1=new Address();
_person.Addresses.Add(_address1);
_address1.Person=_person;

Address _address2=new Address();
_person.Addresses.Add(_address2);
_address2.Person=_person;

_session.Save(_person);
```

Now Addresses is an `HashedSet<Address>` and when I try to add _address2, "Add" method return false because Address Id is null and the object cannot be added... _address1 Id is null too!

How to resolve?

Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set some properties on the Address and implement object equality so that the set implementation can test equality.  For example, I doubt the Address Id is a good test for equality.  Rather, you would want to test the number, street, city, etc for equality.